# iptables rules on server start

Tags: iptables

I used to use following script to control iptables rules:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Get LSB functions
. /lib/lsb/init-functions


IPT="/sbin/iptables"


INET_IFACE="eno1"
#INET_IFACE=""

UNPRIPORTS="1024:65535"

start_fw()
{
    echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

    $IPT -F
    $IPT -X

    $IPT -P INPUT DROP
    $IPT -P FORWARD DROP
    #$IPT -P OUTPUT DROP

    ...
}

flush_fw()
{
    $IPT -P INPUT ACCEPT
    $IPT -P FORWARD ACCEPT
    $IPT -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
    $IPT -F
    $IPT -X
}

stop_fw()
{
    flush_fw
    echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
}

# Check that the package is still installed
[ -x $IPT ] || exit 0;

case "$1" in
start)  log_begin_msg "Starting firewall: iptables"
        start_fw
        log_end_msg 0
        ;;
stop)   log_begin_msg "Stopping firewall: iptables"
    stop_fw
        log_end_msg 0
        ;;
save)   log_begin_msg "Saving firewall: iptables"
        iptables-save > /etc/iptables.rule
        log_end_msg 0
        ;;
restart) log_begin_msg "Restarting firewall: iptables"
    start_fw
        log_end_msg 0
        ;;
*)      echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/iptables-rules start|stop|save|restore|restart"
    #|reload|force-reload
        exit 1
        ;;
esac
exit 0
```

And registering it as a service using
    sudo update-rc.d iptables-rules defaults

But it does not work any more in ubuntu 18
What should be done to correctly run it on ubuntu 18?